Forest Package Alignment Help
Using the forest package, I am trying to make:
\Tree 

[.Red-Shirt

[.Black-Pants [.Red-Black-Outfit ] ]

[.Blue-Pants [.Red-Blue-Outfit ] ]

[.Red-Pants [.Red-Red-Outfit ] ]

[.Gold-Pants [.Red-Gold-Outfit ] ] ]

With the text this is not a problem:

But I can't get latex to use actually images(to give better visual representation):
[.\includegraphics{Red Shirt.png}

[.\includegraphics{Black Pants.png} [.etc... ] ]

[.\includegraphics{Blue Pants.png} [.etc... ] ] 

[.\includegraphics{Red Pants.png}[.etc... ] ]

[.\includegraphics{Gold Pants.png} [.etc... ] ] ]

(Error Below):


Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Welcome! forest doesn't provide a \Tree command as far as I'm aware. This looks more like qtree or tikz-qtree.

It seems that you are using tikz-qtree, since that uses the . before the node label, and uses a \Tree command. What you're doing should work, but you can't have blank lines in your tree source code.

It's not obvious what you're trying to do as forest doesn't provide a \Tree command. Here's a forest example with the structure you want which uses standard images from a standard TeX tree.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  forked edges,
  [{\includegraphics[scale=.1]{cow}}
    [{\includegraphics[scale=.1]{cow-black}} [{\includegraphics[scale=.1]{cow-brown}}]]
    [{\includegraphics[scale=.1]{cow-brown}} [{\includegraphics[scale=.1]{cow}}]]
    [{\includegraphics[scale=.1]{cow-black}} [{\includegraphics[scale=.1]{cow-brown}}]]
    [{\includegraphics[scale=.1]{cow-brown}} [{\includegraphics[scale=.1]{cow}}]]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}


